# ImageButton event listener won't work inside ScrollView -> HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android

`ImageButton` event listener is not working.

Here's my code (updated):

XML:

```
<ScrollView ...>
    <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       ...
       >
       <HorizontalScrollView
          ...
          >
          <LinearLayout 
         android:orientation="horizontal"
     ...
         >
             <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/img_btn1"
     />
          </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Java code:

```
public class Main extends Activity{
    ImageButton imgBtn1;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        imgBtn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_btn1);
        imgBtn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.w("onClick", "ImageButton Clicked");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This code is not working. Thanks for any help.

Comment: post your whole activity code.

Comment: other codes are just declarations and initializations.

Comment: as per user Uttam suggessted initialize ImageButton and get view then declare onClick(), so try his code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine on mine side:

> setContentView(R.layout.vhscroll);
>
> ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);

```
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(VHScrollViewActivity.this, "You clicked image button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

and xml code is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ScrollView  android:id="@+id/scrollview" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
            <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imagebutton1" android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="100dip" android:src="@drawable/sample_0" android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</.......>
```

Comment: guys actually my code is working. sori,  its a typo error... tnx for all the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-----

```
  ImageButton imgBtn1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.img_btn1);        
  imgButn1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "+", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Uttam. Guys it is still the same with my code above. its not working... I already initialized my button, but i did not show it above. this code it not working. pls help me...